# rails plugin for github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I need help on figuring out how to create a repository on github to store a rails plug-in that i wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What part of the process are  you stuck on? If you have an account, there's a 'New Repository' button near the top right of the main github page. Once you create the repository, it'll walk you through how to clone it and commit to it.

If you're already past that point, please let us know what step you don't know how to do, and people will be able to help you much more effectively. Tell us what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead if you think you're doing the right thing but are getting errors.

The [*Making a Plugin* Railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/33-making-a-plugin) is a good place to start for the process of creating the plugin itself.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working. My problem was the no plug-in found. I thought that I saved the wrong directories. NOT. Instead of 'git://github.com/user_name/repo_name'. Needed to do this: 'http://github.com/user_name/repo_name/'. Changed from git to http and the ending slash.

Answer (score -1):

just go create an account/login to github and then create a repo and it will give you exact instructions on how to do set it all up